# How to skip header and footer for Seeds in DBT (Data built tool)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Want to skip header and footer for CSV file used in seeds folder .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use metadata information when retrieving data from a file.
Using the `METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER` field you can check how many lines there are in the file and discard the first and last.

More about [Querying Metadata for Staged Files](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html).

Example:

```sql
 SELECT metadata$filename
      , metadata$file_row_number
      , t.$1
   FROM @mystage1 (file_format => myformat) t
QUALIFY MIN(metadata$file_row_number) OVER(PARTITION BY metadata$filename) < metadata$file_row_number
    AND MAX(metadata$file_row_number) OVER(PARTITION BY metadata$filename) > metadata$file_row_number;
```